Existence of norm 1 vector in Hilbert space that gives distance via inner product
I am trying to prove the following:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $Y\subset H$ a closed subspace, and $x \in
 H \backslash  Y$. Then there exists a unique $z\in Y^\perp$ with $\| z
 \| =1$ and $\langle z,x \rangle = dist(x,Y)$.

I know that I can find a unique vector $y\in Y$ with $dist(x,Y)$ and this gives that $x-y \in Y^\perp$, but I don't know how to get something with the norm $1$ and inner product properties from this. I also considered applying the Riesz representation theorem to the function defined by $f(x) = dist(x,Y)$, but I don't know of any way to guarantee the representation vector I get from this has norm $1$.

As you noted, there exists a unique $y \in Y$ s.t. $\|x-y\|=\text{dist}(x,Y)$ and $x-y\in Y^\perp$. Since $x\in H\setminus Y$, $x-y\neq 0$. Thus, we may choose $z=\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}$. It is clearly a unit vector and $z\in Y^\perp$. Hence, as $y\in Y$, we have $\langle z,y\rangle = 0$. So,
$$\langle z,x\rangle = \langle z,x-y\rangle = \frac{\|x-y\|^2}{\|x-y\|} = \|x-y\| = \text{dist}(x, Y)$$
To prove uniqueness, let $z’ \in Y^\perp$ be another unit vector with $\langle z’,x\rangle = \text{dist}(x,Y) = \langle z,x\rangle$. Then $\langle z’-z,x\rangle = 0$ and, as $z’-z\in Y^\perp$, we also have $\langle z’-z,y\rangle = 0$. Hence,
$$\langle z’-z,z\rangle = \frac{1}{\|x-y\|}\langle z’-z, x-y\rangle = 0$$
So $z’ = z + (z’-z)$ is the sum of two orthogonal vectors. By Pythagorean theorem,
$$1 = \|z’\|^2 = \|z\|^2 + \|z’-z\|^2 = 1 + \|z’-z\|^2$$
Therefore, $\|z’-z\|=0$ and $z’=z$.
